# Relating the binomial probability distribution to the Poisson Distribution in an example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Reading the textbook Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis 3rd ed, by Rice. I've come up on an example that I'm trying to extend beyond the text:

[image]

So I am trying to obtain one of the stated Poisson probabilities, but using the binomial distribution instead. I'm not sure if I am interpreting things right to get my stated goal. For instance let's take trying to get $\text{Number of Deaths} = 0$. From the Poisson Probability this is given as $0.543$.

With the given information I am able to calculate a "probability" but I'm not sure what it means:

$$np = \lambda \\ \Rightarrow p = \frac{\lambda}{n}$$

So we know that $n = 200$ and $\lambda = 0.61$, meaning

$$p = \frac{0.61}{200} = 0.00305$$

I took this as meaning the "probability of dying from horse kick". Here is where I get stuck trying to convert the problem into a binomial distribution problem. I could see framing things in terms of deaths -no deaths and that may possibly look like:

$$\binom{200}{109}(0.00305)^{109}(0.99695)^{91}$$

But how would I go about things if I wanted to get  1 death, 2 deaths,...etc? How could I frame things to get the same (or close to) Poisson probabilities stated but with a binomial distribution instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binomial distribution with $n=200$ and $p=0.00305$ measures the number of "successes" in 200 independent trials, each with a probability of "success" of 0.00305.  If you want "success" to be "death" and "trial" to be "corps-year", you have a bit of a problem.  For each of these 200 corps-year "trials", each one either succeeds (one death "success", singular) or fails (no deaths), so you can't model multiple deaths (successes) per corps-year (trial).

If you really want to apply the binomial distribution here, you probably want to think of a "trial" as a person-horse encounter with a per-encounter probability of getting kicked to death equal to $p$.  How many encounters are there over 200 corps-years?  Well, we don't know, but it's probably a lot.  Let's suppose that there are $n=34000$ person-horse encounters in 200 corps-years.  What's the probability that a single encounter leads to a kick death?  Well, from the data above, there were $65\times1+22\times2+3\times3+1\times4 = 122$ deaths, so that's $p=122/34000=0.00359$.

Now, how do we use this $Binom(n=34000,p=0.00359)$ to get the probabilities we want?  Well, the number of kick deaths per corps-year will be distributed with binomial distribution where $p$ is the same as before but $n$ is the number of person-horse encounters *per corps-year*.  Since 34000 was the 200 corps-year total, the number of encounters per corps-year was $n=34000/200=170$.

Now, since the number of kick deaths $X$ in a year has distribution $Binom(n=170, p=0.00359)$, we can calculate:
\begin{align}
P(X=0) &= (1-0.00359)^{170} = 0.543 \\
P(X=1) &= 170(0.00359)(1-0.00359)^{169} = 0.332 \\
P(X=2) &= \left(170 \atop 2\right)(0.00359)^2(1-0.00359)^{168} = 0.101
\end{align}

How did I know that the right number of person-horse encounters to assume was 34000?  I didn't.  The number doesn't really matter.  Pick something else reasonably "big" (like 5000, say), and redo the math.  You'll get roughly the same answers.

Note: Taking a "trial" to be a person-horse encounter was also pretty arbitrary.  If you prefer, define a "trial" as a single person (who can only die once) or as a horse (who, if it kills a person, is probably going to be euthanized and won't get a chance to kill again).  Any unit that can result in either zero or one deaths such that separate units can be considered reasonably independent will do.

Answer (score 3):

The random variable to which Bortkiewicz attributes the Poisson distribution with expected value $0.61$ is the number of such deaths in each corps in each year. Thus if $n$ is the number of soldiers in each corps and $p$ is the probability that  a soldier is killed in this way during a year, then $np=\lambda = 0.61.$ So let $X$ be the number of such deaths in a particular corps in one year. Then we have
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=3) = \binom n 3 p^3(1-p)^{n-3} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} p^3 (1-p)^{n-3} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\big(np\big)^3 }{3!}\cdot {} \underbrace{ \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3} \cdot \left( 1-\frac\lambda n \right)^{-3} }_\text{These approach 1 as $n\,\to\,\infty$} {} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac \lambda n \right)^n \\[12pt]
\to {} & \frac{\lambda^3}{3!}\cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot e^{-\lambda} = \frac{0.61^3 e^{-0.61}}{3\cdot2\cdot1} \quad \text{as } n\to\infty.
\end{align}